# Unix / linux permissions setup for shared hosting with Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, permissions, web-hosting

I'm in the process of setting up a server from a clean CentOS 5 install. What is the best permission structure (users, groups, unix permissions) for running a single instance of apache for multiple users? Ideally, it should satisfy these requirements:

- Each user's websites are stored in a subdirectory of their home directory. Users can edit files and permissions.
- Apache can read the websites of all users.
- No user can read the website files of other users.

Bonus question: how to add PHP and/or Perl and/or Ruby to Apache without allowing any users to access any other user's files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I did:

1. chown user_name:www-data website_dir
2. chmod g+s website_dir # this makes new files/directories in that catalog owned by www-data user (standard Debian webserver user)
3. Then any user-created file that's group-readable can be accessed by webserver, and user can do chmod g+w if they want directory/file to be also writable by webserver (like configs/upload etc)

Downside of that is that user www-data runs all the scrips so user can get another user data using php/ruby/perl/whatever is run on webserver.

Next step would be using something like mod_suphp or mod_suexec to run user scrips with privledges of that user.

Comment: What group memberships do each user have? Is the user a member of www-data? Wouldn't they be able to read another user's website_dir?

Comment: No, you would not make the user members of the www-data group.